# Vertically align paragraph in center of a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Here is my code. Could you guide me how to align the paragraph in the center of rectangle using both css and d3.js.

Also why is there a space at the start of paragraph. Should the paragraph not start from the rectangle's y position?

```js
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

let text = [
  "WHO Coronavirus disease situation dashboard presents official daily counts of COVID-19",
  "Data Analysis",
  "Javascript",
  "Compare Performance of S&P 500 Index against other Indices"
];

let rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", d => d)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("stroke", "black")

let texty = svg
  .selectAll("boxestext")
  .data([0, 150, 300, 450])
  .enter()
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", (d, i) => 200)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 0)
  .attr("y", d => d)
  .attr("class", "boxes")
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .attr("class", "mytext")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "mytext" + i)
  .style("font", 50)
  .html((d, i) => "<p>" + text[i] + "</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-0XfwGD1nxplHpehcSVI7lY+m/5L37PNHDt+DOc7aLFckwPXjnjeA1oeNbru7YeI4VLs9i+ADnnHEhP69C9CqTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is probably due to margin. You can change that in css by declaring element's margin 0.

```
element {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The best way i've come to center elements in css is:

```
.className {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

You can set `<p class="classname"></p>` or in the css file instead of .className refer to p, but this will apply to all your paragraphs. Note that transform: translate changes the reference point of your element from top left to (in this example) center. Therefore your element may overflow from the left which can't be viewed with scroll